# How to Deal with Huge Data in Keras to Avoid MemoryError?

Tags: keras, out-of-memory

I am using Kears to train an autoencoder. Each of my input vector is [1 256], and I have to load around 10^7 such vectors to train them as a whole in order to extract features. When I try to load them, Keras gives a MemoryError. Yes when I use a smaller training set, it works.

I have set the initial virtual memory of the disk to 16384MB. I want to know the limit/maximum size of arrays allowed in Kears. Or is that because my GPU memory is too small?

- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):   Windows7
- TensorFlow backend (yes / no):  yes
- TensorFlow version:  1.13.1
- Keras version:  2.2.4
- Python version:  3.7
- CUDA/cuDNN version:  NVIDIA Quadro K620M
- GPU model and memory:  2048MB

The following is the configuration of the autoencoder

```
ConvFilters = [128, 128, 128]
KernelSize = [[5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1]]
stride = [1, 1, 1]
ArraySize = [1, 256]
DenseLayerDims = [256, 196, 128, 64, 32, 16, 4]
        # Encoder
        InShape = (self.ArraySize[0], self.ArraySize[1], 1)
        EncoderInput = Input(shape=InShape, name='Encoder_Input')
        x = EncoderInput
        i = 0
        for CurFilter, CurKernelSize, CurStride, in zip(self.ConvFilters, self.KernelSize, self.stride):
            x = Conv2D(filters=CurFilter,
                       kernel_size=CurKernelSize,
                       strides=CurStride,
                       kernel_regularizer= CurRegulariser,
                       activation=self.activation[0],
                       padding='same',
                       name = 'Conv2D_' + str(i))(x)
            i += 1

        self.shape = K.int_shape(x)
        x = Flatten(name='Flatten_Tensor')(x)

        i = 0
        for DenseLayerDim in self.DenseLayerDims:
            x = Dense(DenseLayerDim,
                      activation=self.activation[1],
                      kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
                      bias_initializer = RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0),
                      kernel_regularizer= CurRegulariser,
                      name = 'Dense_Encoder_' + str(i))(x)
            i += 1

        latent = x  
        self.encoder = Model(EncoderInput, latent, name='Encoder')

        # Decoder
        # The middle hidden layer needs not to be involved
        LatentInput = Input(shape=(self.DenseLayerDims[-1],), name='Decoder_Input')

        i = 0
        ListDenseDim = self.DenseLayerDims[0:-1]
        ListDenseDim = ListDenseDim[::-1]
        ListDenseDim.append(self.shape[1] * self.shape[2] * self.shape[3])
        x = LatentInput
        for DenseLayerDim in ListDenseDim:
            x = Dense(DenseLayerDim,
                      activation=self.activation[1],
                      kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
                      bias_initializer = RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0),
                      kernel_regularizer= CurRegulariser,
                      name = 'Dense_Decoder_' + str(i))(x)
            i += 1            

        x = Reshape((self.shape[1], self.shape[2], self.shape[3]), name='Construct_Tensor')(x)
        i = 0
        for CurFilter, CurKernelSize, CurStride, in zip(self.ConvFilters[::-1], self.KernelSize[::-1], self.stride[::-1]):
            x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=CurFilter,
                                kernel_size=CurKernelSize,
                                strides=CurStride,
                                kernel_regularizer= CurRegulariser,
                                activation=self.activation[0],
                                padding='same',
                                name = 'Conv2DTranspose_' + str(i))(x)
            i += 1
        x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1,
                kernel_size=self.KernelSize[0],
                kernel_regularizer= CurRegulariser,
                padding='same',
                name = 'Conv2DTranspsze_Last')(x)    
        x = Activation(self.activation[2], name='Decoder_output')(x)
        if self.CustomActivation[0] == 1:
            DecoderOutput = QPWC(self.CustomActivation[1], DataType = self.precision, name='QPWC')(x)
        else:
            DecoderOutput = x
        self.decoder = Model(LatentInput, DecoderOutput, name='Decoder')

        # Autoencoder
        self.autoencoder = Model(EncoderInput, self.decoder(self.encoder(EncoderInput)), name='autoencoder')
```

Comment: Where does your code crush? When building the dataset or when training?

Comment: You are probably interested in `model.fit_generator`

Comment: Crashed when building the dataset

Comment: In this case, please post the code that builds the dataset, so you can have a more accurate answer

Comment: @josoler. When I try to run this, the error happens. `RawDataIn = np.zeros((self.CreateFileNum*self.ArraySize[0], self.ArraySize[1]), dtype=self.precision[0]) CreateFileNum=10**7 ArraySize = [1, 256]`

Comment: @josoler. Anyway, does generator in fit_generator produce one batch of data to be trained each time? After training, it seems I will have to use predict_generator(generator...) to test performance. But my case is that the testing dataset IS also the training dataset. So how can I retrain my training data for prediction? Thanks.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code for building the dataset in the question. No answer will be accurate enough based on the current question and comments

Comment: Consider using smaller batch_size. Using smaller batch size should help in avoiding OOM issues

Comment: @josoler. That is exactly the line where the error happens. Let me put numbers in it `import numpy as np RawDataIn = np.zeros((10**7, 256), dtype='float64')`

Comment: You might not need to do that but I can't tell since I can't see the actual code that builds the dataset

Comment: @josoler Anyway, I solved the issue by generating one row of the [10**7, 256] data each iteration and having the row written into an xlsx file immediately. The whole xlsx file can be stored in the disk without memory issue. Then I made my own data_generator function in that minibatches of rows in xlsx file were read as per randomly shuffled row numbers in each epoch. Thanks a lot for your guidance on using fit_generator()!!!